# How to solve a generalized eigenvalue Problem for multiprecision in Python

Tags: python, eigenvalue, mpmath

I want to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem for multiprecision in Python ( A.C = (lam).B.C where A and B are 3000x3000 matrices and C is 3000x1 vector. (lam) is the eigenvalue.). So I have installed MPMATH. But I can't find a Python program for a generalized eigenvalue problem. How can I solve  a generalized eigenvalue problem for multiprecision in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`scipy.linalg.eig`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html#scipy.linalg.eig), which will solve ordinary or generalized eigenvalue problems.

Answer (score 1):

`mpmath` version 0.19 includes some functions related to eigenvalues. See http://mpmath.org/doc/0.19/matrices.html#linear-algebra